# Rewriting integral with distribution function

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions

Let $X$ have distribution function $F(x)$. I need to rewrite $\int_x^\infty (y-x)dF(y)$ to $\int_x^\infty \mathbb{P}(X>y)dy$.

I know $\mathbb{P}(X>y)=1-F(y)$, so I thought I should manipulate the first integral to get something with $F(y)$ instead of $dF(y)$. I thought about introducing an extra integral (i.e., writing $y-x$ as an integral such as $\int_0^1 (y-x) dc$), but that didn't really help me.

Any tips on how to rewrite this integral to obtain the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use integration by parts. With $dv=dF(y)$, use $v=-\int_{y}^\infty dF(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the survival function $S:=1-F$, $$\int_x^\infty[S(y)dy+(y-x)dS(y)]=[(y-x)S(y)]_x^\infty=\lim_{y\to\infty}(y-x)S(y)$$vanishes if $S$ decays fast enough for its integral on $[x,\,\infty)$ to be finite, so your two integrals are either both $\infty$ or both of the same finite value.